# Where can I find documentation for the preview() and show() function for VideoClips?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, moviepy

I just want to see how exactly they work, and I can't seem to find them in either moviepy or pygame's websites. Basically I just want to see at what time a user presses a specific key during a clip, and record that time/possibly insert an image at that time while the movie is playing. I know moviepy does that already to some extent, but it's only for mouse clicks.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you can find a basic level of documentation via `help(Modulename.Functionname)`, but don't rely on it much as it is an abstract version of its documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source code but no answer. I ended up editing the source code, and while that works, I would much rather do something else than that if possible.

To have a more elaborate answer to the rest of my question, basically it's not something I think is feasible to directly edit the video file WHILE it's playing. I also don't know if it would be a good idea to save every single and just combine them. I was able to find an extremely efficient, but niche solution by modifying the preview frame while it plays, and having that persist across every new frame. Then I saved JUST the overlay to a file, and can use that however else I feel.

I have seen no other threads/users actually deal with moviepy in this way, so feel free to PM me or ask on the thread if you want more info.

Source code [here](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/io/preview.py)